# When using Yolov5 and Python 3.9.7 I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: python, access-violation, yolov5

I have tried all of the answers that reference "exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" (Which means access violation) but none of them work. I followed the exact instructions on the Ultraytics web site on **another machine and it works fine**, but the machine I must do the work on give me the access violation. The code from the site is:

```
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, custom

# Images
img = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg'  # or file, Path, PIL, OpenCV, numpy, list

# Inference
results = model(img)

# Results
results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.
```

When I debug it I never get past the torch.hub.load statement.

I've tried (1) various version of Python 3.6 - 3.10, (2) reinstalling Yolov5, (3) Virtual environments. I think it may be related to privileges on this machine but I'm not sure where to look.